# how to update Array List contains custom class(3 parameters) and to modify only one specific parameter

Tags: java, android

button onclick that i kept in wordadapter class and i need to update the count every time when i click more than once.

```
final Button buttonName = (Button) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.listitems_addcart);
    if (currentPosition != null) {
    buttonName.setText(currentPosition.getButtonnName());
    buttonName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            ArrayList<Order> orderItems = new ArrayList<>();
            Context context = getContext();

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(currentPosition.getCount()== 0) {
                    String currentPrice = currentPosition.getmPrice();
                    String currentPriceName = currentPosition.getmItemName();
                    int currentQuantity = currentPosition.updateCount();
                    orderItems.add(new Order(currentPrice, currentPriceName,currentQuantity));
                    Toast.makeText(context, "The" + currentPriceName + currentPosition.getCount()+ "  no has been added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                   //its returning -1 here int index= orderItems.indexOf(new Order(currentPosition.getmPrice(), currentPosition.getmItemName(),currentPosition.getCount()));
                    Log.v("context", "the value of"+ index+ "maain activity");
                    //error//            orderItems.set(index,new Order(currentPosition.getmPrice(), currentPosition.getmItemName(),currentPosition.updateCount()));
                    Toast.makeText(context, " "+ currentPosition.getmItemName() + currentPosition.getCount()+ "  no has been added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: Please ask yourself, "is that code readable?" Please consider reading how to edit question and code so that it is presentable.

Comment: I've formatted your code for readability because as posted your code formatting was not good making it difficult to read. In the future I strongly recommend that you do this yourself. Formatting is very important because if your code is not in a standard accepted format, it's not very readable, and if it's not readable, it's not understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a sample code for testing object equality.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author Chirag
 */

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Order> d = new ArrayList<>();
        Order s = new Order("Stack", "Overflow");
        //creating an object 
        Order s2 = new Order("Stack", "Overflow");
        //creating another object with same value
        d.add(s);
        //adding to list
        System.out.println("s == s2: " + ((s == s2) ? "Yes" : "No"));
        System.out.println("s.equals(s2): " + (s.equals(s2) ? "Yes" : "No"));

        System.out.println("values of object s: name:" + s.getName() + ", val:" + s.getVal() + ";");
        System.out.println("values of object s2: name:" + s2.getName() + ", val:" + s2.getVal() + ";");

        System.out.println("list contains s2 an object with same values as object s: " + (d.contains(s2) ? "Yes" : "No"));
    }

    static class Order {

        private final String name, val;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getVal() {
            return val;
        }

        public Order(String name, String val) {
            this.name = name;
            this.val = val;
        }
    }
}
```

and the output of this code is

```
s == s2: No
s.equals(s2): No
values of object s: name:Stack, val:Overflow;
values of object s2: name:Stack, val:Overflow;
list contains s2 an object with same values as object s: No
```

or even you replace code `Order s2 = new Order("Stack", "Overflow");` to `Order s2 = new Order(s.getName(), s.getVal());` then the result will not change

---

For retrieving the index of the required object, consider the following code

```
    ArrayList<Order> d = new ArrayList<>();
    d.add(new Order("Stack", "Overflow"));
    d.add(new Order("Ask", "Ubuntu"));
    d.add(new Order("Super", "User"));

    for (Order o : d) {
        if (o.getName().equals("Super") && o.getVal().equals("User")) {
            System.out.println("index of Super User: " + d.indexOf(o));
        }
    }
```

> Result> index of Super User: 2

You can replace with your values in if statement in for-each loop

Answer (score 0):

Use the counter inside the `onClick()` method but before if condition.

Like

```
int count = 0;

    public void onClick(View v){
        count++;
        if(...){
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: its always returning -1 when i am using arraylist.indexof() though it containg objects

Comment: arrayList.indexOf(...) method only returns -1 when the object you passed not found in the arraylist

Comment: And I've don't get what you actually want to ask.

Comment: Order p= new Order(currentPrice, currentPriceName, currentQuantity);
                                                     int index = orderItems.indexOf(p);
                                                    Log.v("if loop",""+ index +"value");   //in log showing index value -1 //

Comment: in the above code thouugh arraylist contains objects the indexof() shows the index -1 only

Comment: It shows -1 because java compares object for equality not explore the contents of it to treat it as the same object.

Comment: Look on the another code I am posting. And try to run that code snip manually.

Comment: bro, i need to get the index of an object that i stored in arraylist how can i..indexof() method is always returning -1

Comment: how can know the index of an  object tthat was in arraylist bro